# Laravel AdminLTE - How to call method and use its data in view

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I am using Laravel AdminLTE and I have it all configured, there is just one part I do not understand. I made my route like so:

```
Route::get('/admin/painlevel', function () {
    return view('painlevel');
});
```

and I have this method in app/Http/Controllers/v1/PainLevelController.php

```
public function index()
{
     return PdTpainlevel::select('pkpainlevel as id', 'painlevel_name as name')->get();
}
```

How would I call that method and display the data in my painlevel view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current route is merely returning the `view('painlevel')` directly.

You need to update your route to:

```
Route::get('/admin/painlevel', 'V1\PainLevelController@index');
```

In your controller:

```
public function index()
{
  $data = PdTpainlevel::select('pkpainlevel as id', 'painlevel_name as name')->get();

  return view('painlevel', compact('data'));

}
```

You might want to start glancing through the documentations, start with [Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing), [Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers) and [View](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views)

Comment: add `=` symbol after `$data` Variable otherwise it will give error

Answer (score 0):

route create like this

```
Route::get('/administrator', 'administrator\LoginController@index');
```

and controller create like this

```
 public function index()
{
    $data['title']="Admin | DashBoard";
    $data['name']="Dilip Singh Shekhawat";
    view('administrator/menu_bar',$data);
    return view('administrator/dashboard',$data);
}
```

its working .